# Redirect all www addresses to non-www web addresses

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect all traffic from www.domain.com/page to domain.com/page?

I need to disallow traffic to web addresses that include the www. The reason is that I have an SSL certificate that only works with non-www web addresses. If users try to access https://www.domain.com, they get a certificate error.

Comment: Do you need this to be protocol aware (https and http) or just work for http?

Comment: it's not protocol aware, I have a Drupal module that takes care of that, it redirects to https when it's an webpage that requires authentication

Comment: Please check: [How to redirect non-www to www url in drupal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260976/how-to-redirect-non-www-to-www-url-in-drupal).

Answer (score 6):

Uncomment lines 93 and 94 in the .htaccess file that comes with Drupal in the web root.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewiteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

EDIT: If the certificate requires https, edit the second line to read:

```
RewiteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve that in Drupal 7,  editing your .htaccess

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```